# What can set the system clock?

Tags: pi-zero-w, raspbian-buster, raspbian-lite, system-clock

I'm testing various clock sources on a Raspberrypi Zero W with Raspbian Buster Lite. After removing the fake hardware clock

```
sudo apt remove --purge fake-hwclock
```

and disabling ntp

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp false
```

at reboot the date is 2019-02-14 instead of 1970-01-01 as expected. What can be the cause of this behavior?

Even disabling the service systemd-timesyncd

```
sudo systemctl stop  systemd-timesyncd
sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
```

at reboot the date is 2019-02-14.

The output of `timedatectl status` just after reboot is

```
               Local time: Thu 2019-02-14 11:14:38 CET
           Universal time: Thu 2019-02-14 10:14:38 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/Rome (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

I don't have `/var/lib/systemd/clock` but `/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock`, the output of `ls -l` on that file is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-timesync systemd-timesync 0 Nov 19 23:01 /var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock
```

The timestamp is the shutdown time.

Since I purged `fake-hwclock` I don't have `/etc/fake-hwclock.data`.

`systemd-timesync` seems stopped

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service 
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; disabled; vend
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           └─disable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
```

Additional information, maybe relevant.

1. I installed [weewx](http://www.weewx.com/), a software to manage  weather stations, but i have no stations connected so I'm using the simulator driver.
2. I use the [autohotspot](https://www.raspberryconnect.com/projects/65-raspberrypi-hotspot-accesspoints/158-raspberry-pi-auto-wifi-hotspot-switch-direct-connection) script to connect to a know wifi router or automatically generate an hotspot access point if no network is found

Comment: @goldilocks If I undertstand correctly is the fake-hwclock package that writes that timestamp and I removed it

Comment: Whoops, missed that, all apologies -- but how about `systemd-timesyncd`? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=200385 Very likely fake-hwclock was superseded by that in buster.

Comment: @goldilocks that's interesting but disabling the service doesn't solve the issue (see my edit)

Comment: Could you add the output of `timedatectl status` to your post?

Comment: And check the timestamp in `/var/lib/systemd/clock` and `/etc/fake-hwclock.data`, just in case one of them matches that 2019-02-14 date.

Comment: Also check that `systemd-timesync` isn't being pulled in by something else -- `disable` will not prevent it being invoked if another service requires it (but `mask` will by replacing it with a no-op placeholder).

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I added the info you requested in comments.